# React native passing functions from main App.js file to screens in navigation using TabNavigator and StackNavigator

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

In App.js file I have function:

```
resetToken = () => {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (error) {
            ...
        }
    };
```

And navigation component:

```
<MyRootNavigation resetToken={this.resetToken} />
```

And in MyRootNavigation:

```
const SimpleStack = TabNavigator({
        Settings: {
            screen: SettingsScreen
        },
        Notification: {
            screen: NotificationScreen
        },
        ...
```

How does SettingsScreen know about resetToken function?

Comment: I forgot to write, my solution was screenProps:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props